# How to change value with JavsScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with JavaScript.I have created a function *divCreate* where i am creating a small table. And then i am calling that function which is displaying on the HTML page. Now i have some other values , so i am calling another function which i want to implement in that table and change the value of 5 and Rs 100/litre so some other value which is not happening with `.innerHTML`.All these needs to be done with JavaScript, not jQuery.

---

```
function divCreate(node){   
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var text = document.createTextNode('description');
    img.src = "";
    span.id = 'float-description';
    img.id = 'float-image';
    span.appendChild(text);
    div.appendChild(span);
    div.appendChild(img);
    $table = "<table id = 'resultTable' padding=0px; textAlign =left;><tr><td width=30px>" + "Qty" + "</td>";
    $table += "<td>" + "Rate" + "</td></tr>";
    $table += "<td class='qty'>" + "5" + "</td>";
    $table += "<td class='rate'>" + "Rs 100/litre " + "</td></tr></table>";
    div.innerHTML += $table;
    div.className = 'Desc';
    div.style.position = "absolute";
//    div.style.textAlign = "center";
//    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nodeValue to update text nodes.

```
function changeValue(selector, value){
   var ele = document.getElementsByClassName(selector)[0].childNodes[0];
   ele.nodeValue = value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e7nXn/5/

Comment: Thank you Sir..this is the solution

Comment: Sir i have one more question , how can i center span tag  without disturbing the table part.

Comment: How do you mean a span inside a td?
td span {text-align: center;}

Comment: <div><span></span><table></table></div>. i mean the span tag outside the table but inside the div tag.

Comment: SPAN with centered text: text-align: center; display: block;

Answer (score 0):

put 5 and Rs inside a  with id and then change it.

example:

```
$table += "<td class='qty'><span id='number'> 5 </span></td>";
$table += "<td class='rate'><span id='rs'> Rs 100/litre </span></td></tr></table>";
```

Then change it using:

```
var numberElement = document.getElementById('number');
numberElement.innerHTML = 'your value';
```

Comment: You need to use element.nodeValue

Comment: Try the console to see if there is any js error in your page